# Android Studio Development. EditText

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, android-studio, android-edittext

Im looking to make a simple app that involves the user to input an integer and depending on that integer, the same number of EditText will appear. For example, if the user inputs 5, then 5 EditTexts will materialize right below. I dont need help with the layout, just the java code. Im new to programming and im not quite sure how to approach this. thanks.

Comment: This site is for help with code you have already written.  If you edit your question with the code you already have and what happens when you run it, someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for creating EditTexts programmatically inside a loop. Use

`EditText editText = new EditText(this);` `// declare the editText`
`linearLayout.addView(editText);`  `// add the editText to the parent view, wchich is a linear layout here.` inside a loop with the number entered in editText as limit.

For more reference and example about creating views dynamically, refer [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/05/add-and-remove-view-dynamically.html) link.

Comment: yes your ans should be accept able ..but add a little bit help

EditText editText = new (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
int count = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
for (i=0; i<=count;i++) 
{
linearLayout.addView(editText);
}

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Abe